# Set HTML elements to random object key:value pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to use the "database" I have made to cycle through some the quotes at random when the button is clicked and changing the existing quote in the HTML to the random quote and the existing author in the same way

```
var myDatabase = [
    {quote:"I have learned silence from the talkative...", author:"Khalil Gibran"}, 
    {quote: "One of the blessings of old friends that you can afford to be stupid with them." author:"Ralph Waldo Emmerson"},
    {quote: "Once we accept our limits, we go beyond them." author:"Albert Einstein"}
 ];
var newQuote = document.getElementById('displayedQuote');
var newAuthor = document.getElementById('author');

$("#quoteButton").click(function() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*database.length)
    newQuote = myDatabase.[rand].quote;
    newAuthor = myDatabase.[rand].author;
});
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Can we get some more info about this?

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but please not to get an item by index out of an array using square brackets there is no need to use a dot separator -- it should be `myDatabase[rand].quote`, not `myDatabase.[rand].quote`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your "Database" has syntax errors. It should read:

```
var myDatabase = [{
  "quote": "I have learned silence from the talkative...",
  "author": "Khalil Gibran"
}, {
  "quote": "One of the blessings of old friends that you can afford to be stupid with them.",
  "author": "Ralph Waldo Emmerson"
}, {
  "quote": "Once we accept our limits, we go beyond them.",
  "author": "Albert Einstein"
}];
```

Secondly, you're mixing vanilla JS with Jquery. Whilst this isn't technically wrong it's much easier to read if you just stick to one or the other

```
var newQuote = $('#displayedQuote');
var newAuthor = $('#newAuthor');
```

Lastly, the syntax in your click method is incorrect. You're assigning a value to the newQuote and newAuthor variables rather than manipulating the element. What you want to do is use the .text() method to add the object values to the DOM.

Also, you don't need the dot notation before the [rand] integer and you want myDatabase.length not database.length

```
$("#quoteButton").click(function() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myDatabase.length)
    newQuote.text(myDatabase[rand].quote) 
    newAuthor.text(myDatabase[rand].author)
});
```

Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/mark_c/pen/pExxQA

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the syntax of the OP's definition of the `myDatabase` array of JavaScript objects. Your modification merely quoted the property names, which is not needed for object literals, only within a string which purports to be JSON. The rest of the answer is quite right and well explained.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - Correct about the property declarations but there's syntax errors due to the fact that there are missing commas in the 2nd and 3rd objects.

Answer (score -1):

Something like that ?

```
var myDatabase = [
{quote:"I have learned silence from the talkative...", author:"Khalil Gibran"}, 
{quote: "One of the blessings of old friends that you can afford to be stupid with them." author:"Ralph Waldo Emmerson"},
{quote: "Once we accept our limits, we go beyond them." author:"Albert Einstein"}
 ];
var newQuote = document.getElementById('displayedQuote');
var newAuthor = document.getElementById('author');

$("#quoteButton").click(function() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*database.length)
    $(newQuote).text(myDatabase[rand].quote);
    $(newAuthor).text(myDatabase[rand].author);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that there is nothing significantly different between your code and [mark_c's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40118361/215552). That answer, however, includes a detailed explanation of what was wrong with the OP's code and what he did to fix it. Something to keep in mind as you continue answering questions.